# Tailwind does not work on Install - React

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I followed the instructions in this documentation and Tailwind styles are not applied? Why?

https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app

Is the documentation wrong?

Pictures to prove that it is not an error on my part.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app

All the official documentation on tailwindcss.com does not work.

The only step-by-step guide that actually works is here:

https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/how-to-use-tailwind-css-with-react-9dd78bbdc0e0

Also, postcss must be latest version: npm install postcss@latest

Answer (score 0):

There is a newer version for `tailwindcss` v3. and these Documintations are for v2.

In this docs:

```bash
npm install -D tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9
```

this installs the newest version. And docs explain the older.

After you build `tailwindcss.config.js` file and css file.

You need to run this command in the terminal:

```bash
npx tailwindcss init
```